# Retrofit 2 - null response body

Tags: android, retrofit

I am trying to convert following response with `Retrofit 2`

```
{
    "errorNumber":4,
    "status":0,
    "message":"G\u00f6nderilen de\u011ferler kontrol edilmeli",
    "validate":[
        "Daha \u00f6nceden bu email ile kay\u0131t olunmu\u015f. L\u00fctfen giri\u015f yapmay\u0131 deneyiniz."
    ]
}
```

But I am allways getting `null` response in `onResponse` method. So I tried to look at error body of the response with `response.errorBody.string()`. Error body contains exactly same content with raw response.

Here is my service method, `Retrofit` object and response data declerations:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/Register")
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
Call<RegisterResponse> register(
        @Field("fullName")  String fullName,
        @Field("email")     String email,
        @Field("password")  String password);

public class RegisterResponse {
    public int status;
    public String message;
    public int errorNumber;
    public List<String> validate;
}

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
client.interceptors().add(new Interceptor() {
    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        final String content = UtilityMethods.convertResponseToString(response);
        Log.d(TAG, lastCalledMethodName + " - " + content);
        return response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body().contentType(), content)).build();
    }
});
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build();
domainSearchWebServices = retrofit.create(DomainSearchWebServices.class);
```

I have controlled response `JSON` with [`jsonschema2pojo`](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to see if I modled my response class wright and it seems OK.

Why Retrofit fails to convert my response?

**UPDATE**

For now as a work around I am building my response from error body.

Comment: Did you set the Json Converter? like below
`RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                    .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))`

Comment: @problemsolver yes I did. I have added the relevant code.

Comment: @problemsolver I have used `addConverterFactory` not `setConverter`

Comment: What response status do receive? You can check it using calling method `response.getStatus()`

Comment: According wikipedia:
`400 Bad Request`
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
So  Retrofit takes it as an error response

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I have solved the problem. When I make a bad request (HTTP 400) Retrofit doesn't convert the response. In this case you can access the raw response with `response.errorBody.string()`. After that you can create a new Gson and convert it manually:

```
if (response.code() == 400 ) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse - Status : " + response.code());
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    TypeAdapter<RegisterResponse> adapter = gson.getAdapter(RegisterResponse.class);
    try {
        if (response.errorBody() != null)
            registerResponse = 
                adapter.fromJson(
                    response.errorBody().string());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you should always check if body or error body is null.

Comment: I am having a similar issue, can you please advise? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261481/assigning-reference-when-accessing-json-response

Comment: Thank you boss. You save my Time. :)