# Getting Null Response using Retrofit Library in android

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit Library in my app for network requests.My code is given below:

**1. MyAPI.java(Interface)**

```
    public interface MyAPI {
    @GET("/{roomID}")
    Call<Messages>loadMessages(@Path("roomID") String roomID);
}
```

**2. Message.java**

```
    public class Message {

    String user;
    String message;
    //String roomID;

    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return(message);
    }
}
```

**3.Messages.java**

```
    public class Messages {
    List<Message> items;
}
```

**4.MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String roomID = "548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("http://pms.vebific.com:81/chat/index/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    MyAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
    Call<Messages> call = myAPI.loadMessages(roomID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<Messages>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<Messages> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.e("Response", String.valueOf(response.body()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error","---------------");
        }
    });

}
```

}

URL to be used is :

```
http://pms.vebific.com:81/chat/index/548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5
```

**Expected Response:**

```
 [
  {
"_id": {
"$id": "56963d96da036c6c05815e63"
},
"room_id": "548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5",
"user": "Jeevan Verma",
"id": 479,
"message": "\\uD83D\\uDC30",
"date": 1481587559734,
"status": "sent"
},
{
"_id": {
"$id": "56963d8cda036c6c05815e62"
},
"room_id": "548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5",
"user": "Jeevan Verma",
"id": 479,
"message": "\\uD83D\\uDE0A",
"date": 1481587559734,
"status": "sent"
},
{
"_id": {
"$id": "56964454da036c6c05815e64"
},
"room_id": "548b737c0eadfb00eb93891bb28242e5",
"user": "Jeevan Verma",
"id": 479,
"message": "\\uD83D\\uDC2D",
"date": 1481589296434,
"status": "sent"
}
]
```

When i am using it in the browser,i am getting response.

While using Retrofit ,i am getting null response .I might be missing something ,i guess.Please help me to fix it. Please tell me how to read response using Retrofit.

Comment: Do you mean `response` is null?

Comment: @bigdestroyer ,      24599-24599/com.example.deepakr.retrofitdemo E/Response﹕ null

Comment: Try to remove last slash (`/`) from your base URL. Maybe this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757619/retrofit-2-null-response-body?rq=1

Comment: Now onFailure() method is executed .   01-22 12:39:32.916  26405-26405/com.example.deepakr.retrofitdemo E/Error﹕ ---------------

Comment: Try to log the `Throwable` and post the stacktrace

Comment: E/Error﹕ com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Seems that server response is not what you expect, and GSON doesn't know how deserialize. Make the request in browser and post the JSON response.

Comment: Please check the edited question.I have mentioned the expected response .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101368/discussion-between-bigdestroyer-and-deepakr).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your api definition to return `Call<List<Message>>` instead of `Call<Messages>`:

```
Call<List<Message>>loadMessages(@Path("roomID") String roomID);
```

and

```
MyAPI myAPI = retrofit.create(MyAPI.class);
    Call<List<Message>> call = myAPI.loadMessages(roomID);

    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<List<Message>> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            Log.e("Response", String.valueOf(response.body()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.e("Error","---------------");
        }
    });
```