# Retrofit 2 does not parse response in case error

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 in my project.
I have a problem with below scenario.

When I call to `API` and `server` tell me that the r`equest was not executed` with the `error code` is `4xx` or `500` with details message of the problem.

But seems that `retrofit` understands that it's an `http error` and did not collect the `error message` from `Server`.

**I see the closely same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757619/retrofit-2-null-response-body) but it was not resolved my issue.**

I completely get response success and I'm sure that there no problem in my implementation.

```
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Response<CustomResponse> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
    Log.d("Response : ", response.body(), response.code()); // here i got response.body() is null if response code is not 200, if response code is 200 -- it work well as I expected.
    onRequestSuccess(response);
}
```

I have a look at `Response` class in `retrofit` and I see below code:

```
  private Response(com.squareup.okhttp.Response rawResponse, T body, ResponseBody errorBody) {
       this.rawResponse = checkNotNull(rawResponse, "rawResponse == null");
       this.body = body;
       this.errorBody = errorBody;
  }
```

And

```
  public static <T> Response<T> error(ResponseBody body, com.squareup.okhttp.Response rawResponse) {
      return new Response<>(rawResponse, null, body);
  }
```

Seems that when `response` code from `server` was not `200`, `retrofit` understand that it's error and set `body` as `null`.

So any one can help to get the "correct" value of `response body` in this case?

Comment: Just use response.errorBody()

Comment: it was not help. response.Body().string() = ""

Answer (score 2):

Use something like that:

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){
    response.body()
} else{
    response.errorBody()
}
```

Comment: As I said above, a same question is existing here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33757619/retrofit-2-null-response-body?lq=1 but in my case response.errorBody().string() return empty string

Answer (score 2):

You have to capture the error body and parse it to your errorModel when the server's response isn't correct. For example:

```
try {
        // call to retrofit
        Response<SimpleAnswerModel> response = call.execute();
        if (response.isSuccess()) {
            // Do something interesting
        } else {
            Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorModel> converter = apiService.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(ErrorModel.class, new Annotation[0]);
            ErrorModel errorModel = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
            // it fails!
            resetNewAlarm();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // connection fails!
        resetNewAlarm();
    }
```

Comment: import okhttp3.ResponseBody;
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Converter;
import retrofit2.Response;

Answer (score 0):

Try to parse the response like this:

```
@Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Void> call, Response<Void> response) {
                //hideLoadingDialog();
                if (response.isSuccess()) {

                    Toast.makeText(ProximityFeedbackActivity.this, "Feedback successfully sent", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Void> call, Throwable t) {
                //hideLoadingDialog();
                ProximityFeedbackActivity.this.finish();
                startThankYouActivity();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error in Feedback submission " + t.getMessage());
            }
```

Comment: you mean I could use Void type for response?

Comment: Yes you can @Phan Dinh Thai

Answer (score 0):

As others have said

```
if(response.isSuccessful()){
    response.body()
} else{
    response.errorBody()
}
```

is the correct way of handling errors.

In the `string()` method there is a call to a `readString` method

```
  /** Removes all bytes from this, decodes them as {@code charset}, and returns the string. */
  String readString(Charset charset) throws IOException;
```

Based on the comment `response.errorBody().string()` will return the error the first time you call it. Successive calls will return an empty string.

Even if you don't have a call in your code but you have a breakpoint and you inspect the value of `string()` afterwards it will be empty.

Comment: But nulling a errorBody seems very strange, because it returns string but only once. Seems like a spy message that burns after reading.